# How do I store form data temporarily if the form has to be refreshed and re-populated with that data?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm working on a recipe input form. The current version of the form is very basic....takes the data entered and inserts it into a recipe table.

I want to change this form so that the ingredients are no longer a simple text entry....rather i want it to be selected from a list of ingredients.
Here's what I've done so far...
- created a "recipe" table which has all the recipe data
- created an "ingredients" table which will be the list of ingredients to select from
- created a "recipeingredients" table which will be the list of ingredients selected for the recipe. this is just a id table...recipe_id and ingredient_id.

Here's what I need some direction on...
- When the user is in the addrecipe page, they would start entering in some information. When they get to the add ingredients portion they will have to click some sort of link that will open a new page to select ingredients.  When they click that link, I would like to save all the form data they have already entered so this data can be repopulated into the form when they are done selecting ingredients.

How should this data be stored for temporary use? 
SESSION variables? 
DB entry without commit? 
POST the variables back and forth between pages?

Please let me know if I can provide more information to be clear...
Thanks!

Comment: Any remaining questions? Otherwise accept my answer or at least vote, please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use SESSION variables. That's the cleanest way in my opinion. A DB entry without commit looks a bit like a dirty hack to me. By the way, writing to a file is much faster. Using POST and input type hidden form fields could also be acceptable but keep in mind that the data is included in the html source code in clear text. And for bigger data it can make your source code a mess. You'd better store them in a temporary file. So, if you're using sessions anyway and your data isn't too big go for SESSION variables. Moreover if the data is of any confidential nature using SESSION variables or protected files on the server is obligatory.